# encriptyr el appsettings.json cuando esta publicado

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

tengo la cadena de conexion de la BDD en el appsettings.json cuando se realiza la publicacion modifico el appsettings.json por los datos de produccion luego de esto quiero encriptar esta cadena como lo hago
es un api hecho con net core 5

Comment: Mas que encriptar, hay que proteger. Puedes hacerlo con variable de entorno, o utilizando secretos. Dale una mirada a este doc [Almacenamiento seguro de secretos de aplicación en el desarrollo en ASP.NET Core] (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-7.0) Para que te des una idea y puedas completar la pregunta. Si bien [se puede encriptar](http://www.developerslearnit.com/2022/07/how-to-encrypt-decrypt-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core-6-0.html), depende si estas en un cluster de servidores es un problema. Avisanos si profundizamos con ejemplos